# Add Attachment from Notes and Attachment related list in a VF Email template

Tags: visualforce, email, visualforce-template

I have a requirement and I appreciate your help on this.

We have a custom object, where users create records and upload spreadsheets in "Notes & Attachment" related list.

Our requirement is, we wanted to create a VF email template that adds the attachment (xls) of the record. This VF email template will be used in our standard Approval Process.

How do i go about?

Regards,
Satish

Answer (score 1):

Messaging:attachment documentation should help you to form the attachment by yourself rather than asking user to fill in excel if data is derived from salesforce objects and fields

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_messaging_attachment.htm

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_messaging_emailTemplate.htm

The code mentioned is as below

```
<messaging:emailTemplate recipientType="Contact"

relatedToType="Account"

subject="Case report for Account: {!relatedTo.name}"

replyTo="support@acme.com">

<messaging:htmlEmailBody>
<html>
    <body>
    <p>Dear {!recipient.name},</p>
    <p>Attached is a list of cases related to {!relatedTo.name}.</p>
    <center>
    <apex:outputLink value="http://www.salesforce.com">
        For more detailed information login to Salesforce.com
    </apex:outputLink>
    </center>
    </body>
</html>
</messaging:htmlEmailBody>

<messaging:attachment renderAs="PDF" filename="yourCases.pdf">
<html>
    <body>
    <p>You can display your {!relatedTo.name} cases as a PDF</p>
    <table border="0" >
    <tr>
        <th>Case Number</th><th>Origin</th>
        <th>Creator Email</th><th>Status</th>
    </tr>
    <apex:repeat var="cx" value="{!relatedTo.Cases}">
    <tr>
        <td><a href = 
             "https://na1.salesforce.com/{!cx.id}">{!cx.CaseNumber}
            </a></td>
        <td>{!cx.Origin}</td>
        <td>{!cx.Contact.email}</td>
        <td>{!cx.Status}</td>
    </tr>
    </apex:repeat> 
    </table>
    </body>
</html>
</messaging:attachment>
```

Lets say you want exact attachment that user has modified ,then consider sending as link

here is some example for same

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="hai" recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="Case">
 <messaging:htmlEmailBody >
<p>Attachment to download link</p>

<apex:repeat value="{!relatedTo.Attachments}" var="a">
<p><a href="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, a)}">{!a.Name}</a> ({!a.BodyLength} B)</p>
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: Thanks Mohith for sharing the sample code. Actually, the messaging:attachment cannot be used in a repeat statement. 

Please check this link - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12899/using-a-component-to-add-attachments-to-visualforce-email-template-and-showing-e

Comment: If you use in apex component then you have problems.Here in this case you should be fine

Comment: Hi Mohith,

Still it is a problem. The above codes, send an email with attachment (PDF) and inside the attachment it does have the information of the 'Notes & Attachment'.

But, what I am looking for is, the email is sent with 'Notes & Attachment' attachments which will be in xls format.

-Satish

Comment: for example, in an Opportunity record, under Notes & Attachment, we upload "Special-Deals.xls". Now, we want to send an email to our users on the Opportunity record and in the very same email the uploaded "Special-Deals.xls" is attached as an attachment.

I appreciate your help & advise.

-Satish

Comment: You will need to go with second approach of sending just the link while you cant send actual attacment

Comment: Hi Mohith, i tried the 2nd approach. however, the email sent got an attachment (PDF) and when i open the attachment it has the file name with hyperlink. Is it possible to have the attachment in the email itself? click on the link will download it locally.

Comment: whats the code you have currently ?

Comment: <messaging:emailTemplate subject="VF email Approval Template" recipientType="User" relatedToType="Rebate_Claim__c">

<messaging:plainTextEmailBody >

Dear {!recipient.name},

{!relatedTo.CreatedBy.Name} has requested your approval for the following Rebate Claim. Please approve the SRC: {!relatedTo.name}.

</messaging:plainTextEmailBody>

File attachment: click the below url to download the attachment.
 ---->> <<attachment.xlsx>>

</messaging:emailTemplate>

Comment: this is my vf email code.

<messaging:emailTemplate subject="VF email Approval Template" recipientType="User" relatedToType="Rebate_Claim__c">

<messaging:plainTextEmailBody >

Dear {!recipient.name},

Claim Month: {!relatedTo.Claim_Month__c}
Claim Amount: {!relatedTo.Claim_Amount__c}
Claim Currency: {!relatedTo.CurrencyIsoCode }

    <apex:repeat value="{!relatedTo.Attachments}" var="a">
    <p><a href="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, a)}">{!a.Name}</a> ({!a.BodyLength} B)</p>
    </apex:repeat>


</messaging:plainTextEmailBody>